# Update data in an Oracle view

Tags: oracle, view

I just started developing on Oracle.
Is there a way to populate data in a view? I found nothing concrete on the web. My SQL Developer says:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

when I want to update the view with a simple update query:

```
update admin.table1 SET COLUMN1 = '50', SET COLUMN1 = '50'
WHERE COLUMN3 = 'Test'
```

Comment: Your question *really* isn't about updatable views...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why twice **SET COLUMN1 = '50'**?

Check [Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems053.htm), you need to separate columns with comma without the SET keyword, you use SET only once once:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET col1= 'X', col2='Y' WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update data in views, only tables.